# Approximation of bounded Borel functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact space and let $B$ be the space of bounded Borel functions on $K$ equipped with the supremum norm. Show that simple functions (i.e. functions attaining only a finite number of values) are dense in $B$.

I have seen the proof showing simple functions are dense in $L_{p}$ space. Can't see how I can adapt it to this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Proof.** Let $f$ be a bounded Borel function and $\varepsilon>0$. Let $s=\sup_{x\in K} \lvert f\rvert<\infty$, $M=\lfloor M\rfloor+1$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, such that $1/n<\varepsilon$.

Let
$$
E_{k,n}=\left\{x\in K: \frac{k}{n}\le f(x)<\frac{k+1}{n}\right\}, \quad -nM\le k\le nM.
$$
Define
$$
f_n=\sum_{k=-nM}^{nM} \frac{k}{n}\chi_{E_{k,n}},
$$
where $\chi_{E_{k,n}}$ is the characteristic of $E_{k,n}$. Then the range of $f_n$ is finite and
$$
\|f_n-f\|_\infty\le \frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon.
$$

**Second Proof.** This space, the $\mathscr L^\infty(K)$ is the dual of the space $\mathcal M(K)$ of complex (or signed) Borel measures on $K$ (this is not a trivial fact). But assuming this, what you want to show becomes very simple, as it suffices to show that if $\mu\in\mathcal M(K)$, and $\int_K f\,d\mu=0$, for every Borel $f$ with finite range, then $\mu=0$. Or equivalently: if $\int_K \chi\,d\mu=0$, for every Borel characteristic, then $\mu=0$. Or equivalently: if $\mu(E)=0$, for every Borel $E$, then $\mu=0$.

Comment: For your proof II, i thought by riesz representation theorem that the dual of M(K) was the space of continuous functions on K? @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis

Comment: @user108605: Riesz's theorem says that the dual of continuous functions is $M(K)$, but the space is not reflexive.

Comment: It is worth noting that compactness is completely irrelevant (which shouldn't be much of a surprise considering Borel functions disregard compactness pretty much completely). In fact, we only need $B$ to be the family of functions measurable with respect to some fixed (abstract) sigma-field, or even just a field of sets, for the first proof to work.